# Finding a Ljapunov function for discrete dynamical system with 3 variables.

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Consider the discrete dynamical system given by
$(x_{k+1},y_{k+1},z_{k+1}) = f(x_k,y_k,z_k)$, where $f(x,y,z) = (x(1-ay),y(1-b+ax),z+by)$ with $a,b \in (0,1)$ are parameter and we are only interested in $x,y,z \in [0,1]$ with $x+y+z=1$.
The set of all fixed points is given by all $(x,0,z) \in [0,1]^3$ with $x+z=1$.
Now, the Jacobi matrix of $f$ at such a point has $1$ as eigenvalue and so we cannot make assertions about stability with the usual criterion.
How do we find a Ljapunov function for these fixed points?

Comment: The cases $a>b$ and $a<b$ are rather different... Did you try to plot some phase diagrams of the corresponding differential system (for example, in the $(x,y)$-triangle $x>0$, $y>0$, $x+y<1$) to get some intuition?

Comment: They look very different. In the case $a > b$ there is one critial point besides $(0,0)$ and the orbits flow periodically around it (is this a Volterra-Lotka system?). In the case $a < b$ there seems to be no critical point inside the triangle. Do you mean, that in the first case we can find a Ljapunov function while in the second we cannot?

Comment: In both cases, every $(x,0)$ is a fixed point. // No idea what you mean by "critical point inside the triangle". // The remark about the regimes $a<b$ and $a>b$ means that the system might behave differently when $a<b$ and when $a>b$ and that this might have some effects on the stability. For example, if $a>b$, every fixed point $(x,0)$ with $x>b/a$ is unstable while, if $a<b$, it seems that every fixed point $(x,0)$ is stable.

Comment: With critical value i meant fixed points, sorry. Isnt $(x,y) = ((b-1)/a, 1/a)$ a fixed point too? What i meant was that this point is visible (inside the plotted area) in one case while it is not in the other. Do you have an idea how what a candidate for a Ljapunov function might be?

Comment: The point ((b-1)/a,1/a) is never in the triangle x>=0, y>=0, x+y<=1, where the dynamics stays confined, because b<1, hence it is quite irrelevant. The fixed points are exactly the points (x,0) with 0<=x<=1.